# How can one select a specific chapter to replay?

Tags: spec-ops-the-line

I recently finished Spec Ops: The Line (PC) on suicide mission difficulty and wanted to replay specific chapters to find all the intels and make different choices.

However when I go to the 'Select Chapter' menu option, only Chapter 1 seems to be available.

I tried using the mouse wheel, clicking on the map, using a and d to try to select a different chapter but nothing seems to work.

Do I have to replay the game through the Select Chapter menu to unlock the other chapters? Am I doing something wrong on this menu ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the up and down arrows (which are never used elsewhere in the game) to select a different chapter on this screen.